# retrieve data from multiple tables not working

Tags: sql

I have three tables

```
quiz:              activetruck:
id                 id   
name               name
origin             origin
destination        destination
total_trucks       total_trucks
material_type      scheduled_date
scheduled_date     offered_price
offered_price      owner_id
owner_id           subject_id
subject_id
```

I ran this query to extract the common data from both the tables

```
Select * from quiz as cq, activetruck as ca
where cq.origin=ca.origin and cq.destination=ca.destination and 
cq.subject_id=ca.subject_id and cq.total_trucks<=ca.total_trucks;
```

there is a third table supplier and supplier is connected to active truck via **owner_id**

```
columns of suppliers are:
user_id
supplier_name
supplier_company_name
supplier_email
supplier_gst
supplier_pan
supplier_address
supplier_origin
supplier_service
```

I want to fetch all the details of supplier where activetruck.owner_id  = suppliers.user_id
I tried running this but it didn't work

```
Select * from classroom_quiz as cq, classroom_activetruck as ca, classroom_supplier as cs 
where cq.origin=ca.origin and cq.destination=ca.destination and
 cq.subject_id=ca.subject_id and cq.total_trucks<=ca.total_trucks and
 ca.owner_id=cs.user_id;
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: "it didn't work" is no accurate description of a problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: try using JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A left outer join is what you need to use. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

The left outer join on activetruck and suppliers will return the suppliers details that match but in the case where there isn't a match it will still return the activetruck rows. Your query is joining where activetruck matches suppliers but if there isn't a match then it doesn't return anything.

```
SELECT *
FROM classroom_quiz AS cq
INNER JOIN classroom_activetruck ca ON cq.origin = ca.origin
    AND cq.destination = ca.destination
    AND cq.subject_id = ca.subject_id
    AND cq.total_trucks <= ca.total_trucks
LEFT OUTER JOIN classroom_supplier cs ON ca.owner_id = cs.user_id;
```